# Changing Gmail profile when in full screen mode?

Tags: gmail

I have two Gmail accounts. When I click on an email address in a website, it automatically starts a full screen (or wide) mode.

[image: image description]

Is there anyway to change to my secondary profile without exiting this tab?

Comment: Is the account "delegated", or are they two entirely separate accounts?

Comment: @w3d what do you mean by "delegated"? I have searched the dictionary but still not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "New Message" window is opened using the Google/Gmail account you are currently logged in as. It does not seem to be possible to switch to a "delegated" account at this stage.

However, you can set up the "other" account as an email address from which you can "Send mail as" (in Settings > Accounts and Import) and then you can pick the other email address from the "From" dropdown when composing the email.

Official Gmail Help: [Change the "From" address when replying or forwarding](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22377?hl=en-GB)

[image]